# DBFlow (Save Image As Blob)

Tags: android, android-studio, orm

I been trying to save my image(As Blob to the database using DBFlow).
I'm getting an error like this..

```
Error:(90, 30) error: incompatible types
required: Blob
found:    byte[]
```

I Used some tutorial for converting image to byte and save it to database with column blob.

```
 try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(imageURL);
            byte[] image = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
            fileInputStream.read(image);

            ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
            imageModel.latitude = "12345";
            imageModel.img = image;
            imageModel.save();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And lastly my ImageModel.class,

```
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Column;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.PrimaryKey;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.annotation.Table;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.data.Blob;
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.BaseModel;

/**
 * Created by Galvez on 11/17/2015.
 */
@Table(databaseName = AppDatabase.dbName)
 public class ImageModel extends BaseModel {
    @Column
    @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
    long getId;

    @Column
    String latitude;

    @Column
    Blob img;
}
```

What's supposed to be the problem? Am I wrong converting image to blob?

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea.  The Blob class indicates that you want to use BLOB as the underlying database column type.  And you are correct in thinking that a byte array is way to store data in the Blob.  You just have a small implementation issue: the Blob object acts as a wrapper around a byte array.  In Java, you can't cast or coerce the `byte[]` into a `Blob`; you need to use the `Blob` object's methods instead.

So your line of code above should be

```
imageModel.img = new Blob(image);
```

To retrieve image data back out, you might do something like

```
byte[] imageData = imageModel.img.getBlob();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
```